# Custom PHP Function works except on one specific page

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone please help me understand why the below function works in option.php but does not work in main.php? From what I'm seeing, it looks as if the query is not going through when the function is called on main.php; however, it clearly goes through on option.php.

**custom_functions.php**

```
function fetch_options(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<option value=\"{$row['a']}\">{$row['b']}</option>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

**option.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('lib/db.php');
require_once('lib/custom_functions.php');

echo "<select><option value=\"0\">Unknown</option>";
fetch_options();
echo "</select>";
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('lib/db.php');
require_once('lib/custom_functions.php');
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Main</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php include('lib/nav.php'); ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding:none;background-color:#ccc;min-height: calc(100vh - 52px);">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10" style="padding:none;" id="page2">
    <select class="form-control" id="e_CR" name="craft">
        <option value="0">Unknown</option>
        <?php fetch_options(); ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jfunctions.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens in lib/nav.php? Could it be possible that in that file you've closed the database connection? Does it work if you remove that include?

Comment: @JamieBicknell lib/nav contains the HTML code that comprises the nav bar. There is no connection close there. I don't see how I'm closing the connection when the only call to connect is in that function

Comment: So it still doesn't work if you remove the include for /lib/nav.php?

Comment: Any messages in the PHP error log when it fails?

Comment: @JamieBicknell Actually I forgot I'm running a function in the "lib/nav" and it calles for a close to the connection. I completely forgot about that. I'll go take care of that now.

Comment: For that matter, why does `fetch_options()` call `mysqli_close()`? How does it know that you don't plan on doing other queries in the file that calls it?

Comment: @barmar The idea was to connect -> query -> close and I just got ahead of myself on the close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The included nav.php file contained a mysqli_close call and terminated the connection before the fetch_options() function was run.